# Lightswitch Theme Extension TabControlTabTextActiveBrush being ignored

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

The TabControlTabTextActiveBrush setting in my Lightswitch Theme Extension is being ignored.  No matter what value I provide, the setting from TabControlTabTextBrush is being applied to all tabs.  Is this a bug in Lightswitch or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug. I assume you're talking about LS V1? I don't know if been fixed in V2.

Comment: Yup I'm working in LS for VS2010.  Haven't tried yet in VS2012.

Comment: The same problem seems to apply to ScreenTab text.

Comment: I remember that there were a couple of styles that got ignored, from when I first created Luminous Extensions, but I don't remember exactly which ones, other than TabControlTabTextActiveBrush (as it caused me much hair pulling out, lol).